# JsonObject to Json records - format output

Tags: java, json, scala, gson, jsonresponse

I am using the CryptoCompare API to pull the crypto symbol details; the output is 
like below with nested JSON - I need to convert into Rerecords with below format:

`{
   "ETH":{
      "USD":{
         "FROMSYMBOL":"Ξ",
         "TOSYMBOL":"$",
         "MARKET":"CryptoCompare Index",
         "PRICE":"$ 117.74",
         "LASTUPDATE":"Just now",
         "LASTVOLUME":"Ξ 0.01000",
         "LASTVOLUMETO":"$ 1.17",
         "LASTTRADEID":"44473885",
         "VOLUMEDAY":"Ξ 340,510.0",
         "VOLUMEDAYTO":"$ 39,874,960.0",
         "VOLUME24HOUR":"Ξ 418,836.6",
         "VOLUME24HOURTO":"$ 49,126,029.4",
         "OPENDAY":"$ 118.40",
         "HIGHDAY":"$ 119.29",
         "LOWDAY":"$ 114.48",
         "OPEN24HOUR":"$ 117.99",
         "HIGH24HOUR":"$ 119.50",
         "LOW24HOUR":"$ 114.12"
      }
   }
}`

I need to generate output as below - Separate record for each symbol:
Mapping - each Currency NODE - is added as "Sym" field e.g.   "ETH" Node is now "Sym" : "ETH";
rest of the fields are straight move from innermost node "USD"

`{
   "Sym":"ETH",
   "PRICE":"$ 117.74",
   "LASTTRADEID":"44473885",
   "VOLUMEDAY":"Ξ 340,510.0",
   "VOLUMEDAYTO":"$ 39,874,960.0",
   "VOLUME24HOUR":"Ξ 418,836.6"
}`

**Code being used :**

```
import com.crypto.cryptocompare.api.CryptoCompareApi
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

object cryptoComapreMultiSCryptoPriceGson extends App{

  val gson = new Gson()
  val api = new CryptoCompareApi();
  //val response = api.priceMulti("ETH,DASH","BTC,USD,EUR", new Nothing() {})

  val m = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,Object]
  m.put("extraParams", "TestProject")

  val response = api.priceMultiFull(  //to get priceMultiFull
    "ETH,DASH,BTC",
    "USD",
    m)

    //val jsonRec = gson.toJsonTree(response)
    println(response.get("DISPLAY"))

}
```

Any pointers or help?

Comment: The first pointer is to improve your question by formatting the JSON and probably describing in words how the mapping is supposed to be done. Respect the time of the people who help you for free by reducing the guesswork needed to start helping you.

Comment: My bad - I updated the post, please let me know if this is any clear.